# Need help to count on left or right swipe

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programing and I am trying to perform count on left or right swipe.

What I want is when I swipe right to left it counts integer **++** up to 10 times but not go above 10.

And when I swipe left to right it counts integer **--** down to 1 not go below 1.

Note: I am not talking about a loop; what I want is when I swipe every single time it increases or decreases the int count.

What I tried is:

```
package com.usd.swipegesture;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Gesture extends Activity {
    float x1, x2;
    float y1, y2;
    static int b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gesture);
    }

    // onTouchEvent () method gets called when User performs any touch event on
    // screen
    // Method to handle touch event like left to right swap and right to left
    // swap
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
        // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = touchevent.getX();
            y1 = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = touchevent.getX();
            y2 = touchevent.getY();

            // if left to right sweep event on screen
            if (x1 < x2) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //
                b--;
                if (b == 1) {
                    b = 1;

                    if (b == 1) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("1");
                    }

                    if (b == 2) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("2");
                    }

                    if (b == 3) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("3");
                    }

                    if (b == 4) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("4");
                    }

                    if (b == 5) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("5");
                    }

                    if (b == 6) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("6");
                    }

                    if (b == 7) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("7");
                    }

                    if (b == 8) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("8");
                    }

                    if (b == 9) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("9");
                    }

                    if (b == 10) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("10");
                    }

                }
                //
            }

            // if right to left sweep event on screen
            if (x1 > x2) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //
                b++;
                if (b == 10) {
                    b = 10;

                    if (b == 1) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("1");
                    }

                    if (b == 2) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("2");
                    }

                    if (b == 3) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("3");
                    }

                    if (b == 4) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("4");
                    }

                    if (b == 5) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("5");
                    }

                    if (b == 6) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("6");
                    }

                    if (b == 7) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("7");
                    }

                    if (b == 8) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("8");
                    }

                    if (b == 9) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("9");
                    }

                    if (b == 10) {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        tv.setText("10");
                    }
                }
                //
            }

            break;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

but it only shows 1 and 10 value. It is not showing any values between 1 to 10.

I need help to correct my code.

Comment: don't you know **switch** ???

Comment: but i want to use `if statement`

Comment: For Better use declare `TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);` before `if` once only.

Comment: @PratikButani, i did't get your mean, what actually i want is if i swipe right or left it increase or decrease and show in text-view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review your code again :

**See here :**

```
if (b == 1) {
     b = 1; // b is now 1

     if (b == 1) { // if b is 1 then do this 
          TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          tv.setText("1");
     }
     .....
```

> b is always 1, hence it is showing value 1.

Similarly here :

```
if (b == 10) {
      b = 10; // b is now 10
      ......
      if (b == 10) { // if b is 10 then do this 
          TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          tv.setText("10");
      }
```

> b is always 10, hence it is showing value 10.

**These 2 are the reasons why your code not showing other values between 1 to 10.**

Comment: yes i agree with u but i use ~if (b == 1) {
     b = 1; }~ because i don't want to go below 1

Comment: `if (b == 10)
{
b = 10;
}` after removing this code how do i stop int increasing more them 10

Answer (score 0):

**i got my answer:**

```
package com.usd.swipegesture;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Gesture extends Activity {
    float x1, x2;
    float y1, y2;
    static int b = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gesture);
    }

    // onTouchEvent () method gets called when User performs any touch event on
    // screen
    // Method to handle touch event like left to right swap and right to left
    // swap
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
        // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = touchevent.getX();
            y1 = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = touchevent.getX();
            y2 = touchevent.getY();

            // if left to right sweep event on screen
            if (x1 < x2) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right Swap Performed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //
                b--;
                if (b < 1) {
                    b = 1;
                }
                if (b == 1) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText("1");
                }

                if (b == 2) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText("2");
                }
                if (b == 3) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText("3");
                }
                //
            }

            // if right to left sweep event on screen
            if (x1 > x2) {
                // Toast.makeText(this, "Right to Left Swap Performed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //
                b++;

                if (b == 1) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText("1");
                }

                if (b == 2) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText("2");
                }
                if (b == 3) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                    tv.setText("3");
                }
                if (b > 3) {
                    b = 3;
                }

                //
            }

            break;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: consider using a switch statement instead of multiple if's it will run faster, as it wont run (b==2) after it knows b=1, also you could use if else, but this is a situation case is designed for.

Comment: ok how do i implement switch statement instead of if statement with my code, give me a sample.

Comment: I have modified your code and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

using a switch statement to (almost insignificantly) improve efficiently, (every little helps).

default is if none of the cases match.

```
if (x1 < x2) {
b--;

switch(b){
case 1:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("1");
       break;
case 2:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("2");
       break;
case 3:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("3");
       break;
case 4:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("4");
       break;
case 5:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("5");
       break;
case 6:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("6");
       break;
case 7:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("7");
       break;
case 8:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("8");
       break;
case 9:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("9");
       break;
case 10:
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setText("10");
       break;
default:
if (b < 1) {
b = 1;
}

}

}
```